# How can be it known for certain that the number line never ends?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Yes, this is a serious question. And yes, I realize that for every n, where n is an integer, n+1 is greater. Thus, there is no end to the number line (as we know it).

Based on our current understanding, this is certainly the case. However, what if in the distant future this is shown to be wrong? Yes, I realize that this is unlikely, but suppose that the number line "breaks down" at some point, rendering greater numbers "illogical."

It'd be like asking what happened "before" time. Well, that's technically a meaningless question. What if it's revealed in the future that at some distinct point in the number line integers lose all meaning? I know, it's a ridiculous concept, and no, I'm not in fourth grade.

Comment: How would that happen?

Comment: I have no idea. I did ask this of my old math professor and he stated something about it being too close to dinner to think of such things. The other professors I've asked never responded, so I can only assume that they thought it was a stupid question.

Comment: You do realize math is an abstract construction, don't you?

Comment: I realize that numbers don't exist in actuality. But math still works. I believe that math isn't wholly a human construction. The angles of triangles sum to 180 and 5-5 = 0 independent of humans.

Comment: The angles of a triangle do not equal 180.  Space is curved.  5-5 has no meaning outside of human concept-- instead we have conservation of mass.  We have a number system of Natural numbers.  We have demonstrated it is logically consistant.  Nothing can happen to the system.  It is logically consistant.

Comment: Yes, math does exist but it exists by solely by logic.  A "number" is what we define it to be.  We have defined it to be the natural number system with axioms and inferencees.  We have proven the system to be infinite.  We can "discover" anything different.  Even if we discover logical inconsistencies and *different* systems.  The natural number system will still be the system we defined.  But google "ultrafinitism".

Comment: Some portions of mathematics are man-made.  For example, in the past, 1 was considered a prime number because the definition of *prime number* is man-made and thus is subject to change.  The statement "$n+1>n$" is man-made, and will always be true unless the definitions of the symbols are changed.

Comment: Perhaps this question should be tagged [tag:philosophy].

Comment: Your question is either about philosophy or physic and will lead to endless and pointless debates if treated as mathematical. Hence my close vote.